# "Nuget failed to restore packages", but it worked fine before

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, uwp, nuget-package-restore

After a corrupt registry warning at boot up, I succesfuly got my PC running again by simply restoring windows to the state it was before a certain update. However, for some completely unknown reason, Visual Studio then started behaving oddly. To start with it didn't detect a reference to Renci.SSH.NET, even though it was clearly there. So I went in nuget package manager, uninstalled SSH.NET, with the hope I could just reinstall it after and all would be fine.

Obviously, nothing went quite that smoothly. If I use the package manager GUI, Visual Studio tells me "Failed to restore package. Restoring package modifications for 'BlankApplication'.". If I use the nuget console and type `PM > Install-Package SSH.NET`, I get this highlighted in red nightmare:

```
Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SSH.NET 2016.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Install-Package SSH.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

But this makes no sense. It worked perfectly well minutes ago. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling nuget, cleaning the project, clearing everything related to NuGet in %AppData%, but nothing works. Also, please note that this also happens if I try and create a new Blank project.

EDIT: The error also happens with [Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit), with the same symptoms of supposedly not being compatible with `UAP,Version=v.10.0`. I had also added this package to my project before the crash. However I don't get this issue with any other packages that weren't previously installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution:

- Download the latest nuget.exe [here](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe)
- Clear the nuget cache by opening cmd as admin where nuget.exe is, and running `nuget locals all -clear`
- Reinstall everything on your project. It may take a while, but it's fixed my issue.
- If your system appears to be particularly unstable at the moment, create a system restore point. You never know.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.